# Call GUID function more than once in print formatting in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text which I'd like to look like this.

> This is a first guid: "fc52457d-42a5-4ad7-9619-c1513ce60a96" and this is a second one: "f6df6054-c433-48a6-bc22-449b037f4fc9"

I would like to achieve that with .format() but only to reference uuid function once and somehow to call it twice, something like this :
`"This is a first guid: {} and this is a second one: {}".format(uuid.uuid4()*2)`

I don't want to use {0} and {1} notation, and if I put just e.g. {0} instead of empty brackets I will get the same GUID for both instances.
Is there a way to call uuid function many times in .format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
'This is a first guid: {} and this is a second one: {}'.format(*(uuid.uuid4()
                                                               for _ in range(2)))
```

prints:

```
'This is a first guid: c5842b59-795d-452f-b0cd-ba5c7369dde7 and this is a second one: 8c20f372-8044-4b82-bbbd-0e667fb14ed3'
```

You can use the `*` to hand an specified number of arguments to a function. For example:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

>>> L = [10, 20
```

This:

```
>>> add(*L)
>>> 30
```

is equivalent to:

```
>>> add(L[0], L[1])
30
```

This is generator expression:

```
>>>(uuid.uuid4for for _ in range(2))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10e4d1620>
```

Convert it into a list to see what it generates:

```
>>> list((uuid.uuid4() for  _ in range(2)))
[UUID('d45eaf67-5ba0-445f-adaa-318f989e2d60'),
 UUID('58fcaf7f-63af-4c7f-9f01-956db6923748')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from generating and passing multiple UUIDs to the format function as Mike Müller showed, you could also be creative and create your own “UUID string generator” type that creates a new UUID whenever you call `str()` on it:

```
class UuidStringGenerator:
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(uuid.uuid4())

print('First: {uuid}\nSecond: {uuid}'.format(uuid=UuidStringGenerator()))
# First: dd38d750-301b-4dec-bf18-4554a96942d8
# Second: bcb27d9f-378d-401e-9746-043834bece09
```